# Spring - How do I annotate properties in classes

Tags: spring, jackson, spring-data-rest, spring-rest

I have a Java RESTful client that works create and I use Jackson to de/serialize the returned requests (serialize as XML).

For returned classes I don't need to do anything. For the classes I post (serialize) I use com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;

Now with Spring, where the inbound requests can be JSON or XML and the return also can be JSON or XML, do I need to do the equivalent? And if so, what annotation do I use?

Spring pulls in Jackson. But the library it pulls in has com.fasterxml.jackson but not com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.

And... I was not aware there were different Jackson libraries. But as there are, which one does Spring use?

Comment: Did you try `@JsonProperty`? And, what do you mean under the `do I need to do the equivalent?`?

Comment: @Daria I'm trying to figure out what Jackson library Spring includes. If I know the library then I can make use of all this and I can use the Jackson javadocs to set the correct annotations. Do you know what Jackson library Spring uses?

Comment: You can try `mvn dependency:tree` to view which library and what certain version is used in your project (because it various depending what spring version you use)